# Parsing a REST Token Expiry Date

Tags: java, android

I need to parse the expiry date that return by REST WebAPI (written in .NET) which return something like this `Sun, 24 Feb 2019 08:06:26 GMT`.

I tried to parse it this way:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
dateFormat.parse(issuedDate);  //throws java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date - eg try to parse: Sun, 24 Feb 2019 08:06:26 GMT
```

But sometimes, it throws `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date`. Any idea how to parse the date that using this format (eg. `Sun, 24 Feb 2019 08:06:26 GMT`)?

Thanks

### UPDATE

I think I found the problem. The problem is that the Android language is set to "Bahasa Indonesia" which Sunday is not **Sun** but **Minggu**. Any idea how to parse token return by REST API (eg. `Sun, 24 Feb 2019 08:06:26 GMT`) in the language set to language other than English?

Comment: Have you set GMT `Timezone`  in `dateFormat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you use the following code

```
  String cdate = "Sun, 24 Feb 2019 08:06:26 GMT";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date=sdf.parse(cdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: ahhh... I found the problem (I think). In Android tablet locale was using a different language/locale which set to Bahasa Indonesia. So, Sunday is not **Sun**, but **Minggu**.

Comment: yes you should pass  Locale.ENGLISH in output SimpleDateFormat also

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much! I learn a new thing everyday and, heck, a new language!!!